# How to alter the default background color of composable preview without altering android:windowBackground

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I'm currently improving previews in my android app (which is using mostly jetpack compose).

When i only use `@Preview(showBackground=true)` the background color of the preview defaults to almost-black, which makes black text unreadable.

[image]

Sure, i could alter the background color of each preview, but that is overly cumbersome and doesn't work when running the preview on an emulator: `@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF)`

So i went looking where the almost-black default color comes from, and it seems to be the `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/almostBlack</item>` of my ancient `xml` theme. Changing this to white works, but has unintended consequences for my main app :(

[image]

Is it possible to alter the default preview background color without altering `android:windowBackground`?

---

As requested my code:

This is my simplified theme:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/almostBlack</item>
</style>
```

It needs to be applied in the Android Manifest

```
<application
    [...]
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
    [...]
    >
```

I then add the following composable & preview

```
@Composable
private fun HelloWorld(
    title: String
) {
    Text("Hello $title")
}

@Preview(showBackground=true
@Composable
private fun HelloWorldPreview() {
    HelloWorld("Stack Overflow")
}
```

Comment: going to remove your `af` as i think the majority of people here might not even know what it means :)

Comment: Can you provide the code of your previews/themes please?

Comment: I have added the requested code :)